# How to input a word into multiple txt files?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have 3 text files in a particular folder,

`A.txt` `B.txt` `C.txt`

Using batch file i like to input the word `hello` in all the text files in the particular folder.

I am trying,

```
@echo off
echo hello>>*.txt
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
Please guide me how to do it correctly.

I like to have output like,

`hello` in the file `A.txt` 
`hello` in the file `B.txt` 
`hello` in the file `C.txt`

Comment: `for %%f in (A.txt B.txt C.txt) do (echo hello>>%%f)`

Comment: @Biswapriyo that would double the extension and also process subfolders. Also I'd call it [appending to a file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) not **input**.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648]

append hello w/ batch:

```
for %%f in (A.txt B.txt C.txt) do echo hello>>%%f
```

append hello w/ command line:

```
for %f in (A.txt B.txt C.txt) do echo hello>>%f
```

append hello to all .txt files in directory w/ batch.  Works if a space is in the path/filename:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b path-to-parent-folder-with-or-without-double-quotes\*.txt') do echo hello>>%%f
```

append hello to all .txt files in directory w/ command line.  Works if a space is in the path/filename:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /b path-to-parent-folder-with-or-without-double-quotes\*.txt') do echo hello>>%f
```

Answer (score 0):

To add `hello` to each of the text files in a folder, you can use a For loop with `/r`:

```
@echo off

set "src=C:\your\folder"

for /r "%src%" %%A in (*.txt) do (
    echo hello >> "%%~fA"
)
```

For each text file (`*.txt`) rooted in the source (`src`) directory: set as parameter `%%A` and add the line `hello` at the end. `%%~fA` is the fully qualified path name (including the extension) of the `%%A` parameter.

To limit it to just your three files (A.txt, B.txt, and C.txt), you can specify those instead of using the wildcard above - which would look like this:

```
@echo off

set "src=C:\your\folder"

for /r "%src%" %%A in (A.txt B.txt C.txt) do (
    echo hello >> "%%~fA"
)
```

Either way - if you're aiming for a specific folder, `for /r` is what you're looking for.